# Send email via PHPMailer to single email address on MySQL

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

The "search result" brings up a table, and at the end of each row there is an "email-button". Visitor clicks one "email-button" and the system sends an email to that registered "user".

The PHPMailer and the mailing system is working fine, but ONLY with static email!

QUESTION: what do I need to change on the code to send email to the single email what the visitor chooses. I have added a "WHERE" condition to the `$query` but it seems to have no impact.

MAILING FUNCTION WITH THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES IS WORKING

```
$mail->AddAddress("support@domain.co.uk", "John Doe");
$mail->AddAddress("admin@domain.co.uk");
```

WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE IS **NOT** WORKING

```
$mail->AddAddress("$email", "John Doe");
```

ERROR MESSAGE SAYS:

> "Invalid address: Message could not be sent."
>   "Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

```
 <?php

//mailer.php

$dbhost = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; 
$dbuser = 'user_name';
$dbpass = 'password';  
$dbtable = 'tablename';
$db = 'db_name';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db) or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);

if(isset($_POST['requestedEmail'])){
    $requestedEmail = $_POST['requestedEmail'];
    }

//Connecting to database
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);

//Fetching from database table.
$query = "SELECT email FROM db_name WHERE email='". $requestedEmail . "'";

if ($result) 
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  send_mail($row['email']);
}
}
//$email = $row['email']; 
?>




<?php
  require 'PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php';

  $email = $row['email'];      

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                 // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "domainname.co.uk;domainname.co.uk";  // specify main and back`enter code here`up server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "support@domain.co.uk";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "support@domain.co.uk";
$mail->FromName ="Company Name";
$mail->AddAddress($email, "John Doe");

$mail->AddReplyTo("info@domain.co.uk", "Information"); 

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject 3.4";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
 echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent to: " . $email; // $email is not printed out
?>
```

Comment: still not sure I am getting this correcly - you already have the email address from your button press- why do you need to query the DB again to get it?

Comment: this is what i want: perfotm a search >> get result in table with email addresses listed out (one per row) >> then click the button at the end of row and the system will send an email to that email address. OR i dont need to query the DB again? if not, how can i achive this email to be sent?? THANKS!

Comment: This is the row what displays the email address: 
echo $output = '<td id=mail style=color:black;background-color:#eee;min-width:6.5%;> '.$row["email"].'</td>';

Comment: You just need to check your values - `addAddress` will return false if you feed it something invalid. It might help to look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: on if ($result){ do stuff } result is never initiated

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM db_name WHERE email=$row[email]";
```

where is it getting the $row[email] from? you need to have a valid variable in there - such as  from the post array (assuminig you are passing the variable from a form. Something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['requestedEmail'])){
$requestedEmail = $_POST['requestedEmail']}
// other code

$query = "SELECT email FROM db_name WHERE email='". $requestedEmail . "';
```

Then you get the email out of the returned $row (assuming you are using that variable from the returned query

```
$email = $Row['email'];
```

Then you can use $email (without quotes since it is a variable rather than a string):

```
$mail->AddAddress($email, "John Doe");
```

Comment: i took that out. I left only:
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@domain.co.uk", "Information");

it says: "Message could not be sent.

Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

Comment: check my answer - i was typing when you replied: your assigining $email in the wrong place.

Comment: in the TABLE i use: $row[email] to display the email address for visitor.

Comment: i have edited my original codes (please see above - replaced it in my question here too), but still says, it cannot send the email....

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
$mail->AddAddress("$email", "John Doe");
```

Should be changed to this:

```
$mail->AddAddress($email, "John Doe");
```

When passing a variable as a parameter in PHP, you don't use quotation marks around the variable like you would when passing a string. So in your code, you aren't passing the variable $email, you're passing the string "$email".

Comment: This makes no difference - variables are interpolated in double quotes, so these are identical, though the quotes are unnecessary.